# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when post with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello im trying to upload a xlsx file one by one so i can show a status bar, the problem is, i did it with a for loop and while loop sending a request via ajax, but when is on the 40th element it stops and the console shows POST (site.php) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, i tried to do it in the localhost and it works perfect, but when a i try to do it on my external server(godaddy) it shows the error. here is the code.

```
for(j=1;j<=tama;j++){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",       
            url: "ejphp.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {vals: regs, j:j},
            success: function(datos){ 
                console.log(j)
                prog=datos['progreso_r'];
                var id_vac=datos['id_vac']
                var tipo=datos['tipo']
                var tipo2=datos['tipo2']
                var tot_ing=datos['tot_ing']
                prog_p=Math.round(prog*100/tama);       
                $("#progressbar").val(prog_p);
                $("#progreso").text(prog_p+'%');
                $("#datos_vac").text('Id Vacuno: '+id_vac);
                if(prog_p==100){ 
                    $("#aceptar").show("slow");                     
                }
                if(tipo=='error') registro(tipo2, id_vac)
                subir(parseInt(prog)+1);
                return false;
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your server can't pass more than 40 requests, try to increase php memory limit and execution time. And try to browse in godaddy's admin panel.